# Как можно отобразить несколько точек на mapView если координаты этих точек находятся в бд firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Есть база данных, куда приходят данные о местоположение пользователя.
[image: пример данных]

Широта и долгота.
Задаюсь вопрос как можно будет отобразить эти данные на карте?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама карта реализована так. и точки прописаны вручную

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/39520253/5892568 должно быть что-то (предварительно определив POJO класс вашей структуры):

```
        DatabaseReference mProfileRef = 

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Coordinates");
mChildEventListener = mProfileRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                 FirebaseMarker marker = dataSnapshot.getValue(YourMarkerPOJO.class);

                 String latitude = marker.getLatitude();
                 String longitude = marker.getLongitude();

                 LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                 map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title("Title"));
             }
```

Comment: Большое Спасибо!! Очень помогло!